# Dplyr - Filter if any variable is equal to a value

Tags: r, dplyr

I have a dataset `a` with 5 variables and want to filter it like this:

```
a1 <- a %>% filter(var_1 != 1 , var_2 != 1 , var_3 != 1 , var_4 != 1 , variable_5 != 1)
```

I was wondering if anything like this (pseudo code) existed:

```
a1 <- a %>% filter(anyvariable != 1)
```

In other words I would like to get rid of all the rows with value 1, no matter where it appears.
1 is just a random number. It could have been 9, 99, or whatever else!
Thanks!

Comment: Your `|` condition implies you want to filter and keep rows where not all columns have a 1, but your wording says get rid of all rows with a 1 in any column position. Can you clarify?

Comment: Hi Gopala, thanks. It should have been with commas rather than |. The wording is correct.

Comment: Did you meant to remove a row with any value 1 as your code is confusing

Comment: Hi guys, apologies. I want to remove all the rows with a 1 no matter where it appears. In other words, I want to remove all the rows with at least a 1.

Comment: Please check my update.  I guess it should work for what you mentioned

Answer (score 9):

You can use `filter_all` in combination with `all_vars` from `dplyr`, as follows:

```
some_data <- tibble(var1 = c("a", "b", "c"),
                    var2 = c(2, 4, 1),
                    var3 = c(1, 6, 5))

# # A tibble: 3 x 3
#   var1   var2  var3
#   <chr> <dbl> <dbl>
# 1 a      2.00  1.00
# 2 b      4.00  6.00
# 3 c      1.00  5.00

some_data %>% filter_all(all_vars(. != 1))

# # A tibble: 1 x 3
#   var1   var2  var3
#   <chr> <dbl> <dbl>
# 1 b      4.00  6.00
```

This will remove rows in which a variable includes 1. In the above example, this removes the first and third rows. However, be cautious with NA values:

```
some_data <- tibble(var1 = c("a", "b", "c"),
                    var2 = c(2, NA, 1),
                    var3 = c(1, 6, 5))
# # A tibble: 3 x 3
#   var1   var2  var3
#   <chr> <dbl> <dbl>
# 1 a      2.00  1.00
# 2 b     NA     6.00
# 3 c      1.00  5.00

some_data %>% filter_all(all_vars(. != 1))  

# # A tibble: 0 x 3
# # ... with 3 variables: var1 <chr>, var2 <dbl>, var3 <dbl>
```

Note that the second row does not contain a 1, but is filtered anyway. In this specific example, you can avoid such behavior by:

```
some_data %>% filter_all(all_vars(. != 1 | is.na(.)))
```

However, this may not generalize well.

Comment: These answers still work, but the use of scoped variant verbs has been superseded by the use of `across`, `if_any`, and `if_all`. See my [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37363583/dplyr-filter-if-any-variable-is-equal-to-a-value/68218366#68218366) below for code that uses the new syntax.

Answer (score 6):

We might be able to use `rowSums`

```
a %>% 
  filter(rowSums(. !=0) >0)
#    Col1 Col2
#1    1    1
#2    0   24
#3    9    1
```

If I change it to `!=1`

```
a %>% 
   filter(rowSums(. != 1) > 0)
#   Col1 Col2
#1    0   24
#2    9    1
#3    0    0
```

Note that this will remove the rows with all 1s.  In the previous case, it removes the rows with all 0s which is consistent with what the OP mentioned in the post.

#### Update

If the OP wants to remove rows with any 1 (just a number, he can use 9, or 99, or 999)

```
a %>% 
   filter(!rowSums(.==1))
#    Col1 Col2
#1    0   24
#2    0    0
```

#### data

```
a <- data.frame(Col1 = c(1, 0, 9, 0), Col2 = c(1, 24, 1, 0))
```

Comment: I should have added that 1 is just a random value. It could have been 9 or 99 or whatever else. Thanks for the suggestion!

Comment: @Gaspare That is why I put it as `!=0`  You can change it based on the value you have in mind

Comment: If there are NA's in the data, may also need to add na.rm=TRUE

Comment: This works with the pipe, but not without it:

> a %>% filter(!rowSums(.==1))
  Col1 Col2
1    0   24
2    0    0
> filter(a,!rowSums(.==1))
Error: object '.' not found
>

Any suggestions?

Comment: In `tidyverse` we are supposed to use pipes. or else it can be done in `base R` itself  `a[rowSums(a!=0)>0,]`

Answer (score 2):

Here are some convenient functions in the form OP requested:

```
filter_any <- function(...,test_val,na.rm=T)
{
      # JAF 20170316 filter by comparing test_val to any column, returning rows that have test_val in any column
      out <- ... %>% filter(!!rowSums(.==test_val,na.rm=na.rm))
      return(out)
}
filter_exclude <- function(...,test_val,na.rm=T)
{
      # JAF 20170316 filter by comparing test_val to every column, excluding rows that have test_val in any column
      out <- ... %>% filter(!rowSums(.==test_val,na.rm=na.rm))
      return(out)
}
```

Here is the result on OP's test variable:

```
> a
  Col1 Col2
1    1    1
2    0   24
3    9    1
4    0    0
> a %>% filter_exclude(test_val=1)
  Col1 Col2
1    0   24
2    0    0
> a %>% filter_any(test_val=1)
  Col1 Col2
1    1    1
2    9    1
>
```

These functions have the benefit of working without the pipe notation:

```
> filter_exclude(a,test_val=1)
  Col1 Col2
1    0   24
2    0    0
> filter_any(a,test_val=1)
  Col1 Col2
1    1    1
2    9    1
>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try to combine with the `apply` function in the pipeline:

```
dput(df)
structure(list(x = c(1L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 1L), y = c(1L, 
2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 3L), z = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
3L)), .Names = c("x", "y", "z"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-8L))

df %>% filter(!apply(., 1, function(row) any(row == 1)))
  x y z
1 2 2 2
2 2 3 2
```

Comment: This is going to be slower vs. even base subsetting on `rowSums`.

Comment: I agree that `rowSum()` is a much better way to approach the problem.

Answer (score 1):

There is no `filter_each` in `dplyr`, so a solution based on rowSums is a viable one. Posting this very simple base option although one may prefer a `filter` solution so as to incorporate the output into the `dplyr` pipeline with additional operations.

```
set.seed(1)
df <- data.frame(x = sample(0:1, 10, replace = TRUE),
                 y = sample(0:1, 10, replace = TRUE))
df[rowSums(df == 1) == 0, ]
  x y
1 0 0
2 0 0
```

Modifying `1` above to whatever value will make it work for filtering on other values. This solution is considerably faster than the `apply` based `filter` solution and marginally slower than `dplyr` package's `filter` with `rowSums`.

Answer (score 1):

[@George Wood](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4300478/george-wood)'s answer works, but `all_vars` has been superseded by the use of `if_all` inside an existing verb, in this case `filter` instead of the scoped variant `filter_all`. [@George Wood](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4300478/george-wood)'s answers can be updated by changing `some_data %>% filter_all(all_vars(.` to `some_data %>% filter(if_all(.fns = ~ .x`